# Is the Solrj 6.4.x client backwards compatible with Solr 5.2.x?

Tags: solr, solrj

can I use the latest Solrj client 6.4.x to query a 5.2.x solr cloud cluster?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [SolrJ/Solr cross-version compatibility](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj)

> SolrJ generally maintains backwards compatibility, so you can use a newer SolrJ with an older Solr, or an older SolrJ with a newer Solr.

Disclaimer: this clarification does not apply to your question, but I want to add it for sake of completeness.

A big leap was done passing from versions 4.x to versions 5.x and earlier and SolrJ clients were completely redesigned.

So it is not possible use a recent version of SolrJ (5.x and earlier) with a SolrCloud (not Solr standalone) versions 4.x and older.